# how to iter through a table by row by row through the columns and place it into a list in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

list1

```
0, 19.2, 20.3, 21.3, 23.5, 24.6, 25.2, 25.4, 26.2, 26.3, 26.4, 8655, Light
26.2, 25.7, 25.2, 25.3, 22.3, 21.2, 20, 19.2, 19.1, 0, 0, 8655 , Light
0, 0, 54.2, 56.3, 62.3, 63.3, 65.2, 65.3, 65.3, 65.4, 65.4, 8483, Fan
65.4, 65.2, 65.1, 64.2, 63.2, 62.5, 61.3, 56.4, 53.8, 53.2, 0, 8483, Fan
32.3, 33.6, 34.2, 36.3, 34.1, 32.3, 33.6, 33.5, 33.2, 33.3, 33.3, 8470, Fridge
32.3, 34.6, 35.2, 36.3, 34.1, 32.1, 33.6, 33.3, 33.2, 33.3, 33.3, 8470, Fridge
0, 129.3, 2235.6, 2236.2, 2235.5, 2232.3, 2235.6, 2234.2, 2235.2, 2235.4, 2235.6, 8903, WaterHeater
2236.4, 2235.2, 2235.6, 2236.2, 2235.5, 2232.3, 2235.6, 2234.2, 1992.5, 119.3, 0, 8903, WaterHeater
```

Question: How can write the program so that it will iter through the list row by row through columns and append into a list (which will be used for K Nearest Neighbour Predictions)

List:[0, 19.2, 20.3, 21.3, 23.5, 24.6, 25.2, 25.4, 26.2, 26.3, 26.4, 8655, Light]

```
Such that it will be in a list after convert to 2D Array 
List:[[0],
     [19.2],
     [20.3],
     [21.3],
     [26.4],
     [Light]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
l = [0, 19.2, 20.3, 21.3, 23.5, 24.6, 25.2, 25.4, 26.2, 26.3, 26.4, 8655, 'Light']

final_list=[]
for i in l:
    final_list.append([i])
```

If you want to iterate through a table which I'm presuming to be a list of lists, then use the below code.

```
l1 = [0, 19.2, 20.3, 21.3, 23.5, 24.6, 25.2, 25.4, 26.2, 26.3, 26.4, 8655, 'Light']
[26.2, 25.7, 25.2, 25.3, 22.3, 21.2, 20, 19.2, 19.1, 0, 0, 8655 , 'Light']
[0, 0, 54.2, 56.3, 62.3, 63.3, 65.2, 65.3, 65.3, 65.4, 65.4, 8483, 'Fan']
[65.4, 65.2, 65.1, 64.2, 63.2, 62.5, 61.3, 56.4, 53.8, 53.2, 0, 8483, 'Fan']
[32.3, 33.6, 34.2, 36.3, 34.1, 32.3, 33.6, 33.5, 33.2, 33.3, 33.3, 8470, 'Fridge']
[32.3, 34.6, 35.2, 36.3, 34.1, 32.1, 33.6, 33.3, 33.2, 33.3, 33.3, 8470, 'Fridge']
[0, 129.3, 2235.6, 2236.2, 2235.5, 2232.3, 2235.6, 2234.2, 2235.2, 2235.4, 2235.6, 8903, 'WaterHeater']
[2236.4, 2235.2, 2235.6, 2236.2, 2235.5, 2232.3, 2235.6, 2234.2, 1992.5, 119.3, 0, 8903, 'WaterHeater']

final_list=[]

for l in l1:
    for i in l:
        final_list.append([i])
```

You will have your result in final_list.